# Registered Target Instance shows unhealthy in target groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routes, amazon-route53

[image]

I have created a Application Load Balancer(ALB) and registered target groups with Ec2 instance and all the deployment is done in openshift (I have created routes for all registered instances in Openshift). Deployment works fine but the issue is in Target groups registered instances health shows unhealthy and throws message {Health checks failed with these codes: [503]}. How do i make health checks success.

**PS: if i use NLB target group instances shows healthy**.

what am i deploying?

grafana and it works fine only issue is registred instances shows unhealthy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `ALB` is `HTTP/HTTPS` check (URL path), and `NLB` is `TCP` check (port).
So, you might be configured your `ALB` `health check` details for your `OpenShift` cluster after checking your `health check` details. Check the target `URL` of `health check` is valid.

- [Application Load Balancer - health check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html)
- [Network Load Balancr - health check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-health-checks.html)

I hope if help you. :^)

Comment: How to configure ALB health check for open shift or any other cluster, I didn't configure any health check

Comment: As far as I remember, Application Load Balancer is HTTP/HTTPS health check against "/" path, so it will respond `503 status` from `OpenShift`, how about change the `health check` to `TCP port check`, if you can ?  Unfortunately I'm not familiar with AWS configuration, so I can't help you about `AWS` details, but you would check the around health check details between `ALB` and `NLB`, then you can find solution for this issue.